# ModX Revo: Create password protected pages

Tags: content-management-system, password-protection, modx, modx-revolution

I want to create several password protected pages for visitors (clients) to my site. I understand about creating Access and Resource Groups and assigning ModX users to that group - but there are a couple of things I do not understand:

1. How do you set up a login page to access the secure resources?
2. If I set up a user group for my clients and distribute usernames and passwords, will they be able to login to the back end of ModX (/manager) like an admin does?
3. Is is better to just use a plugin like DocPassword that just makes pages password protected (no usernames)?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found this which helped me out a lot:

http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/Login.Tutorials

What I didnt know is that you had to install an add on called 'Login'